# Database for NACA airfoil polars

Tags: airfoil, drag, datasets, polar-curve

Is there anywhere where I can find a database of experimental or CFD-obtained NACA series four or series 6 airfoil data?

I'd like to have access to a relatively large set of high-fidelity drag polars/$C_L \times \alpha$ curves in order to train a neural network for a personal project, and I don't have the time to digitalize the plots in NACA's original contractor reports.

Any help is appreciated. =)

Comment: Resource location questions are explicitly off-topic. Please check the [help] for more details.

Answer (score 3):

1. The technical report [NACA-TR-824](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930090976) has been [digitized](https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/files/file/2538-naca-report-tr-824-digitized/).  The digitized version includes Cl and Cd for 118 airfoils at 3 Reynolds numbers.  To get it, create an account on x-plane.org.  (It's been online sporadically elsewhere over the decades, e.g. [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Douglas_Hunsaker/post/Where_can_I_find_digitized_data_for_the_airfoils_in_Abbott_and_Von_Doenhoffs_book_Theory_of_Wing_Sections/attachment/59d6213979197b807797fa09/AS%3A295349622198273%401447428245441/download/TR824_Digitized.zip).  People associated with the digitizing include Gregory Peter, Gregory Siemens, and James Sonnenmeier.)
2. Convert plots to tables of numbers with [Data Thief](https://datathief.org/) or [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/).
3. At lower Reynolds numbers, http://airfoiltools.com/polar/index lists XFOIL-calculated polars for many of those airfoils, as text as well as plots, e.g. http://airfoiltools.com/polar/details?polar=xf-n0009sm-il-500000:

> alpha    CL        CD       CDp       CM     Top_Xtr  Bot_Xtr
>
> ---
>
> -13.500  -0.9606   0.06449   0.06155  -0.0264   1.0000   0.0073
> -13.250  -0.9745   0.05737   0.05426  -0.0319   1.0000   0.0074
> -13.000  -1.0011   0.04929   0.04597  -0.0377   1.0000   0.0072
> -12.750  -1.0177   0.04406   0.04052  -0.0404   1.0000   0.0073
> ...

You may need some clever webscraping script to collect them all in a NN-friendly format.  Or you could run XFOIL yourself:  they describe exactly how they generated these tables.

Comment: Those polars are at very low Reynolds numbers which are often unsuitable for the particular airfoil. Only model airplane airfoils are well represented on airfoiltools. But maybe the classic by [Abbot and Doenhoff](https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/files/file/2538-naca-report-tr-824-digitized/) is a better choice?

Comment: Aha!  I didn't know that anyone had digitized NACA-TR-824.  Yes, better.  Propose that as an answer.

Comment: I have enough reputation already. Also, it is better to keep all relevant stuff in one answer. So please feel free to add the link to your answer.

Comment: What, no upvote so far? This is an excellent answer!

Comment: Fear not, google will direct people here in due course!